# static content blocks some images in website

Tags: asp.net, image, web-config, asp.net-webpages, static-content

I am using `<static content>` to provide an expiration date in web.config file.
When I include the tag below, some of the **images are not shown** in one of the web pages.

But when I exclude the tag, the website runs perfectly, but I need to include the tag for the optimization of website.

I am using the code below:

```
<location path="images" >
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseExpires" httpExpires="Mon, 1 Apr 2013 00:00:00 GMT"/>
    </staticContent>
</location>
```

I would have included a snapshot but as I need at least 10 reputation to post image, I am not able to do so.

Can someone help?? Thank You.

Comment: are you suing form authentication. Ans the page where the image are not showing is without login?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the page you are having issues with is already cached, and hasn't expired yet (thus no new content is being displayed).

- Remove the `<staticContent>` section from your web.config.
- Expire the cache for all pages in your site (instructions [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/staticcontent/clientcache))
- Add the `<staticContent>` section back into your web.config.